# htaccess redirect with GET values

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to redirect from one url to another. First url has GET values (/product/category/name/something-123/?a=1&b=2), which should be omitted.
After redirection I have all get values in new URL (https://example.com/category/asdf.html/?a=1&b=2) - how can I skip all get values during redirection?

My code:

```
Redirect 301 /product/category/name/something-123 https://example.com/category/asdf.html
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the query string entirely, you'll need to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) instead of mod_alias (`Redirect`). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/category/name/something-123/?$ https://example.com/category/asdf.html [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `QSD` flag discards the original query string (requires Apache 2.4).

*Aside:* Note that you had omitted the trailing slash on your source URL (in the `Redirect` directive), which is what caused the additional slash on the redirected URL when requesting the URL with a trailing slash (as in your example). The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL.

In the above example I've made the trailing slash optional on the requested URL.

Note that you will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Test first with 302s to avoid potential caching issues.